# Is hyperbolic distance on the hyperboloid model holds good even after lorentz transformation

Tags: mathematical-physics, transformation, hyperbolic-geometry, hyperbolic-functions

I found the below link to calculate hyperbolic distance in hyperboloid model but I am looking is this formula is invariant even after performing lorentz transformation on the coordinates

[What's the right way to calculate hyperbolic distance on the hyperboloid model?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1368443/whats-the-right-way-to-calculate-hyperbolic-distance-on-the-hyperboloid-model?rq=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Lorentz transformations prserve distances, they describe the isometries of the hyperbolic plane.

As discussed in the question you referenced, the distance between two points $u$ and $v$ depends on the bilinear form $B(u,v)$ which can be written as

$$B(u,v)=u^T\,\eta\,v
\qquad\text{with}\quad
\eta=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&-1&0\\0&0&-1\end{pmatrix}$$

Now a Lorentz transformation is *defined* as a transformation which does not alter the bilinear form. A Matrix $\Lambda$ is a Lorentz transformation if $\Lambda^T\,\eta\,\Lambda=\eta$. Which means $B(\Lambda u,\Lambda v)=B(u,v)$ and therefore the distance of the transformed points has to equal the distance of the original points.

Comment: I think third 1 should also be -1 rather than just 1

Comment: @vinay: You're right.